# HTML Input (type = file) select from exclusive directory

Tags: html, file, input, types, directory

Hello guys I'm wondering if exists a way to use the input tag from html (type = file) to select a file from an exclusive directory.

For example, I have a directory named 'videos' and I want to select files ONLY from this directory. Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, I have a directory named 'videos' and I want to select files ONLY from this directory. Is that possible?

Nope!

Web pages, as a rule, aren’t allowed to know much at all about the client’s file system, or specify where things go or where they should come from therein.

What you can do in the particular case of videos is to specify [an `accept` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-accept):

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" />
```